# Get byte range positions for a specified time range of an mp3 file

Tags: ios, mp3, avplayer

I'd like to be able to determine at what byte positions a segment of an NSData compressed mp3 file begins and ends.

For example, if I am playing an mp3 file using the AVPlayer (or any player) that is 1 minute long and 1000000 bytes, I'd like to know approximately at how many bytes in the file the 30 second mark happens, then how many bytes the 40 second mark happens.

Note that due to the mp3 file being compressed I can't just divide the bytes in half to determine the 30 second mark.

If this can't be done with Swift/Objective-C, do you know if this determination can be done with any programming language? Thanks!

Comment: do you need the byte position to be on a packet boundary or is in the middle ok?

Comment: Hmm I'm not familiar with packet boundaries. I would need byte position for any time (such as 40 seconds in a 60 second mp3 in my question) and more than just the middle. I am hoping to be able to determine the byte position for any second within any mp3 file. Doesn't have to be exact but it does need to be accurate within a few seconds.

Comment: You can divide the bytes in half to get something close to the 30second mark, even (sort of) with VBR. But what do you need to do with second/offset mapping?

Comment: Thanks @RhythmicFistman, you're right. It turns out I had a different problem to solve. I'll post a brief explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I had a different problem to solve. I was trying to approximate the byte position of a specific time, say, the 4:29 point of a 32:45 long podcast episode, within a few seconds of accuracy.

I used a function along these lines to calculate the approximate byte position:

```
startTimeBytesPosition = (startTimeInSeconds / episodeDuration) * episodeFileSize
```

That function worked like a charm for some episodes, but for others the resulting start time would be off by about 30-40 seconds.

It turns out this inaccuracy was happening because some mp3s contain metadata at the very beginning, and image files stored within metadata can be +500KB, so my calculation of time based on byte position for any episode with an image file would be off by about 500KB (which translated into about 30-40 seconds in this case).

To resolve this, I am first determining the size in bytes of the metadata in an mp3 file, and then use that to offset the approximation function:

```
startTimeBytesPosition = metadataBytesOffset + (startTimeInSeconds / episodeDuration) * episodeFileSize
```

So far this code seems to be doing a good job of approximating time based on byte position accurately within a few seconds.

I should note that this assumes that the metadata for the image will always appear at the beginning of the mp3 file, and I don't know if that will always be the case.

Comment: The CoreAudio `AudioFileStream` API should be able to help you figure out where your audio data really starts.